# My business computer doesnt connect to any ethernet device outside business lan

Tags: networking, ethernet

My computer which i use at work is within a domain. And our internet connection is through some kind of filter. So in Internet Explorer, there is a configured lan setting. When i try to connect any other ethernet device with this computer, i cant even ping the device. How can i solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First step would be asking your question on the right site...

Comment: Please speak to your system administrator.

Comment: Why would a community of Systems Administrators help you skirt the policies that your SAs put in place?

Comment: @ceejayoz, what would you say the "right" site for this question is?

Comment: @tombull89: That's easy: wannabehackerSoonWithoutAJob.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @tombull89 Whatever it is, ServerFault isn't it.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like there is some security that your system administrator setup. I would talk to your IT/System Administrators before you go trying to bypass the security they have put into place. There are a number of different setups that could be "blocking" you.